# Как сделать чтобы появлялись разные блоки при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста. Как видно на картинке мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на определенную локацию, открывалась определенное описание, и при клике на другую локацию, старое убиралось и появлялось новое. И было бы здорово, если при загрузке страницы, было открыто одно из описаний, а не было пусто справа. Подскажите, как код в JS правильно написать, а то я полный новичок. Попробовала с присваиваниями класс active (display:none -> display"block), но там как-то криво все получается :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы хоть показали код, который у вас имеется (html, css, js). Посмотрите [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), чтобы вам ответили.

Answer (score 0):

У меня не было вашего кода, поэтому я написал макет с нужной функцией.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    const a = document.getElementById('oneText');
    const b = document.getElementById('twoText');
    const c = document.getElementById('threeText');

    let yee = 0;

    const d = document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {
        a.style.display = "block";
        yee = 1;

        if (yee == 1) {
            b.style.display = "none";
            c.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    const a2 = document.getElementById('two').onclick = function() {
       b.style.display = "block";
       yee = 2;

       if (yee == 2) {
            a.style.display = "none";
            c.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    const b2 = document.getElementById('three').onclick = function() {
        c.style.display = "block";
        yee = 3;

        if (yee == 3) {
            a.style.display = "none";
            b.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="one" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></button>
    <button id="two" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></button>
    <button id="three" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></button>
    <p id="oneText" style="width: 300px; display: block; position: absolute;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec tempor justo, vitae imperdiet purus. Morbi pellentesque, felis tristique ullamcorper aliquam, nulla lacus volutpat nibh, vitae accumsan arcu urna eu dolor. Donec sed laoreet enim, non blandit odio. Fusce aliquet purus metus, vitae placerat metus consectetur non. In eu purus vitae augue dapibus consequat. Aenean ac aliquet massa, nec ultricies lorem. Aliquam at nisl consectetur, gravida lorem non, consequat risus. Donec ultricies ante mi. Pellentesque et venenatis augue. Cras eu velit magna. In ac tellus arcu. Fusce non luctus leo.</p>
    <p id="twoText" style="width: 300px; display: none; position: absolute;">Vivamus vestibulum sapien ac metus eleifend, eu cursus purus volutpat. Morbi et elit eget lorem blandit rutrum a ac tellus. Proin ut est ante. In sit amet ullamcorper eros. Curabitur vulputate cursus mollis. Etiam a gravida est, in condimentum nulla. Nam non diam non est scelerisque consequat. In malesuada nunc vitae felis rutrum condimentum. Donec non blandit purus. Morbi venenatis tempor quam ut blandit. Sed iaculis neque faucibus, viverra mi id, placerat diam.</p>
    <p id="threeText" style="width: 300px; display: none; position: absolute;">Proin nec consequat magna. Proin eu volutpat mi. Nunc sollicitudin velit nibh, blandit feugiat ante laoreet sed. Cras consectetur neque in eros maximus aliquam. Cras sed semper odio. Vestibulum tempus nulla nec sollicitudin vulputate. Phasellus sed orci sed erat cursus congue quis venenatis tellus. In eget tortor a erat rutrum imperdiet et vel nibh. Vivamus mattis ac lacus et consequat. Aenean eleifend sapien lacus, in cursus lorem gravida nec. Curabitur interdum varius hendrerit. Fusce est elit, vulputate et erat a, convallis consectetur nulla.</p>
```